# kernel like least squares in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, least-squares

Ok so I have four 2d matrix of 100x100 (lets call them A, B, C and D) and I wish to solve the system of linear equations (Y=Xt) for lets say a kernel of 3x3 (in the code below you can see that iA, ..., iB are 3x3 matrices).

In sum i want to do the following in an optimized way:

```
for i=2:size(A,1)-1
   for j=2:size(A,2)-1
      iA=A(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1);
      iB=B(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1);
      iC=C(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1);
      iD=D(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1);

      X=[iA(:),iB(:),ones(size(iA(:)));ones(size(iA(:))),iA(:),iB(:)]
      Y=[iC(:);iD(:)]

      t(i,j,:)=X\Y
   end
end
```

Is there any better way to do this? a kernel-like approach maybe?

Comment: What system(s) are you trying to solve? How are `X` and `Y` related to `A` `B` `C` `D`? What exactly do you mean by "kernel of 3x3"? In all likelihood, the answer to your question simply consists in using the backslash operator wisely.

Comment: What's the bottleneck? Did you profile it?

Comment: @Jubobs A and B are used to produce X, and C and D used to generate Y. The idea here is that for each element in the matrix X and Y change and therefore a different t

Comment: @Divakar no I did not. the point here is that I wished to replace the for loops entirely as they are just used for this specifically. what I wsa looking for is a convolution/kernel like approach

Comment: Although this is not a large matrix (100x100) in this example, it is not necessarily for all cases. Further, I may need to increase the "kernel" size

Comment: @Jubobs i edited the question. in general the kernel is referring to which data is used in each least squares. So a 3x3 uses the closest 9 elements of the voxel, a 5x5 uses the 25 closest elements.